# Showing Python code correctly with appropriately located indents on HTML table

Tags: python, html, css, wordpress

I am currently writing a Wordpress page with HTML and CSS and there's a chunk of Python code I want to insert into a table cell I create with HTML.

However when I create the table, it removes all indents of the Python code and aligns them left or centre automatically.

Is there a way to show Python indent correctly using HTML and CSS?

```
    <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;" scope="row">
   {
    "aa": [
    {
      "xxa": "yya",
      "xxb": "yyb",
      "xxc": "yyc",
      "xxd": "yyd"
    },
    {
      "xxe": "yye",
      "xxf": "yyf",
      "xxg": "yyg",
      "xxh": "yyh"
    }
    ],</th>
    <td>Some text to describe the code on the left cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;" scope="row">
      "bb": 
    {
      "xa": "ya",
      "xb": yb,
    }
    }</th>
    <td>Some text to describe the code on the left cell</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Try <code> python here </code> . - BTW where is python in question?

Comment: The code itself is -

{
    "aa": [
    {
      "xxa": "yya",
      "xxb": "yyb",
      "xxc": "yyc",
      "xxd": "yyd"
    },
This part. I am going to try it with <code>